# What role is the verb in the sentence?

Tags: verbs, tenses, present-tense

The sentence is: "When a static or dynamic function call FC is evaluated with respect to a static context SC and a dynamic context DC, the result is obtained as follows.". This sentence is quoted from [3.1.5.1 Evaluating Static and Dynamic Function Calls](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#id-eval-function-call)

I can't understand the verb "call", shouldn't it be used in the present tense "calling" here?

Comment: Why are you calling it a verb? It's a noun. Nouns don't have tense in English.

Comment: This three nouns , "function", "call",   "FC" ,  are serialized together？Why not using "calling" instead for better

Comment: It's just a compound noun, like peanut butter and dog house.

Comment: Combinations of two noun words are common, but for three or more noun?

Comment: There's no limit because the grammar can always keep branching. You can have a *rubber baby buggy bumper factory worker retirement policy meeting refreshment cart platter* if you'd like. :)

Comment: The "FC", "SC", and "DC" are abbreviations that presumably will be used in subsequent text.  In some styles they would be presented in parentheses.

Comment: And "call", in the computer sense, is more often a noun than a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Call" isn't a verb here; "is evaluated" and "is obtained" are the verbs.

A "function call" is a thing, in this case a procedure, which is either unchanging (static) or dynamic (changing, depending on conditions).

If I rewrite the sentence for clarity, I get something like this:
"A function call (FC) can be evaluated in static (SC) or dynamic (DC) context. 
The instructions to perform this analysis are described next."

Answer (score 1):

Let me break down the following [given] sentence.

> The sentence is: "When a static or dynamic function call FC is evaluated with respect to a static context SC and a dynamic context DC, the result is obtained as follows.". This sentence is quoted from 3.1.5.1 Evaluating Static and Dynamic Function Calls

**Static or dynamic function call FC** is the noun. 
**is evaluated** are helping/verbs